# Frequency of Permutations of Independent Events

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I have $X_i$ independent events which are normally distributed $X_i=N(\mu_i,\sigma_x)$.

If $i=3$ there are 8 permutations, for $i=4$ there are 16. How do I determine the frequency of each permutation's likelihood?

If $i=3$ how often will ${1,0,1}$ occur? I'm interested in the solution for $i>20$ so a numerical approximation is fine.